# UML for Distributed System

Tags: uml, soa, distributed-system

As we known . The sequence diagram in UML is a kind of interaction diagram that shows how processes operate with one another and in what order Between the Class or Object.
Now I am trying to find a diagram in UML or some tools to describe interaction and operation order of distributed system. Is there any diagram or tools which model the interaction between Distributed system like sequence diagram ?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequence and communication diagrams aim to show how "things" interact. These "things" could be objects, components or complete systems

Answer (score 2):

Activity Diagrams are the UML diagram to use in this situation.

[Wikipedia Activity Diagram](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=activity%20diagram%20uml&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CG8QFjAF&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram&ei=idoeUIX_HO2wiQejuoHYBg&usg=AFQjCNEWytTQH2VgbExG2lel7-CbIlt4VQ)

[Agile Activity Diagrams](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=activity%20diagram%20uml&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CHUQFjAG&url=http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/activityDiagram.htm&ei=idoeUIX_HO2wiQejuoHYBg&usg=AFQjCNFu-gG1yBIb9lx5bK9fmeQdPx0gzg)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sequence diagrams to describe interaction between components in a distributed system,  each lifeline designating one of the system components.